# Migrate SVN history to GIT for certain files

Tags: git, git-svn

I am converting a PHP application that is stored in a SVN repository to an MVC framework and I would like to store the new code in a GIT repository.

Most of what I am copying from the old code is Models that we have created over time. The commit history is a very important part of our development process, but to keep the repository simple, I only want the history for those files, not for the entire repository.

Is there a way to export the history of a single file (or a handful of files out of hundreds) from SVN to GIT?

Example:

```
copy-with-history /svn/project/inc/classes/*.mo.php /git/project2/app/Classes/Models/*.php
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `--ignore-paths=` argument you could specify to the `git svn clone` command. The tricky part is to compose a regular expression which includes only that you need. You know your repo better, maybe you could compose a simple list of ignores.

Comment: Can I run that multiple times to merge more files into the repository?

Comment: @yakatz Sounds strange. Normally you should do `clone` once. Why do you want it multiple times? There is `reset` command which allow to re-fetch commits, but it requires a lot of history rewriting.